# How to exclude some fields of subclasses from Apache Commons-> HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode

Tags: hashcode, apache-commons, exclusion-constraint

I am trying to exclude some fields for a subclass during the hashcode generation, and it seems that either I have the option to exclude it entirely or none, but not the specific fields even after specifying it in the exclusion list

For e.g. if I have a

```java
Class Car {
    @HashCodeExclude
    int id

    int modelYear

    String color

    TyreClass tyre;
}

Class TyreClass {
   
   @HashCodeExclude
   int id;

   @HashCodeExclude
   int version;

   float radius

   String colour

   double width
}
```

Now when I try to invoke the method HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode, like:

```java
TyreClass tyreObject = new TyreClass();
type object.setId(1);

Car carObject_1 = new Car();
carObject_1.setId(1);
carObject_1.setTyre(tyreObject);

Car carObject_2 = new Car();
carObject_2.setVersion(2);   /// Changing this value which is to be excluded for hashcode generation
carObject_2.setTyre(tyreObject);

List<String> excludedFields = new ArrayList<>();
excludedFields.add("id");
excludedFields.add("version");
int hashCode_1 = HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(carObject_1, excludedFields)
int hashCode_2 = HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(carObject_2, excludedFields)
```

Since I have excluded the field `version` by adding it to the exclusion list, I was hoping that it would be excluded but it's not.
Can somebody guide me on what I can do to exclude the `version` field of the Tyre object?